# PayPal Adaptive Chained Embedded Passing discount (Coupon) details to Shopping cart contents

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I've just implemented PayPal Adaptive Chained Embedded Flow.I'm curious to know how to pass Coupon details to Shopping cart contents in PayPal Transaction Details Page. I have searched for any documentations unfortunately couldn't find such. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see the screenshot link http://prnt.sc/d8ydx0

Comment: did you ever figure it out how to include coupons with the adaptive payment charge?